# Mock activity class member before onCreate

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I am trying to test an activity using robolectric 3.3.2.
Want to mock and activity's member initialization as the direct call results in NPE.

```
ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController = 
                Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class);
mTestActivity = activityController.get();

Mockito.when(mTestActivity.getCountry()).thenReturn("xxxx");
activityController.setup();
```

Tried out above code, but the setup.() (oncreate) ignores the mock of
getCountry method and invokes the definition from activity.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work like this even if you use spies (`@Spy`, `Mockito.spy()`).

You should use stub:

```
public class MyActivityTest{

    public static class StubMyActivity extends MyActivity {
       Country getCountry() {
           return someSpecialCountry;
       }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        ActivityController<StubMyActivity> activityController = 
                Robolectric.buildActivity(StubMyActivity.class);
        mTestActivity = activityController.setup().get();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen. I tried above solution. But it fails to find the string resource. android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0037 .This exception does not appear when i dont use Stubactivity. Do you see something wrong here ?

Comment: Do you see in log message something like "manifest flie not found"?

Comment: Manifest was in place.But my code was referring to resources from another package.I got it fixed by extending RobolectricTesRunner and adding custom paths.                                                                                                 Now again hit by another issue "R contains final fields, these will be inlined by the compiler and cannot be remapped" , this is happening with new versions of robolectric like 3.2.1, 3.3. etc. Are you aware of this ?